# Putting Contact Tags in Email Template

Tags: groups, templates, tags

I would like to add the tags/groups of a contact into the email body of a template. Is there a shortcode that can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE.

I have [contact group token extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/contactgrouptokens) which provides a list of group users added to, but not for tags.